# How to create PK/FK relationship string and uniqueidentifier?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, guid

I have two entities called User and Student as shown below:

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    //omitted for brevity
}


public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //Foreign key for User
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    //omitted for brevity
}
```

In an MVC project, I use EF Code First and want to create relationship between these entities. What data type should I use as UserId field in User entity? string or Guid (there are Guid values in the Id field of User table)? Could you please give an example?

Comment: **there are Guid values in the Id field of User table** You already have a table ? Why are you asking what type it should be then ? The type of your property should match (in PK & FK table)

Comment: @Shyju I meant ASP.NET Identity User table :) So, I need to create relationship with it but not sure what data type should I use in my custom table?

Comment: @Shyju Any reply please?

Answer (score 0):

You should really use int for ID field for index purposes. Using either Guid or string will be significantly slower than int.

But for your question, the type of `UserId` has to be the same type as `User.Id`

Comment: Yes, I know but I need to create relationship with ASP.NET Identity tables and it use string (GUID) data type as Id field. On the other hand, changing them to Int really a big problem and not performed properly. So, any example please?

Comment: @binary you could change the Identity table's id column to use int instead of string. But that is not easy once you are in production stage. So in your case you are stuck with string since the datatype is varchar instead of Guid in the database

Comment: I tried many different methods on many pages but none of them is working properly. So, the only option is to create a suitable relationship in my custom tables and AP.NET User table. But if I use string, is it possible to create Guid values for the new records in Student table?

Comment: @binary no. I don't think so. The referenced type needs to match each other. Even though the string is a Guid, you still need to make it a string type. Though a Guid is technically a string anyways so you should have no issue with that

Comment: Yes, you are right. But the corresponding data type seems to be nvarchar(128). In that case should I use [MaxLength(128)] for UserId field  in my EF entity? Could you please a proper sample i tour answer?

Comment: @binary your UserId field needs to be the SAME as User.Id there is no way around that. So if your User.id is nvarchar(128) then your UserId field needs to be nvarchar(128) unless you are not making them relational

Answer (score 0):

You can go for GUID in User Entity.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Student
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //Foreign key for User
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: User is the default table of ASP.NET Identity and I do not want to modify User entity. So, in that case should I use Guid or string for UserId field in  Student? If I should string how can I create GUID values for the new records in Student? Could you please modify your answer?